# How to know the status of the pages in a ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm implementing a image gallery with a ViewPager.

Each page load a image from Internet and put it in a ImageView.

The gallery also have a share button (external to the ViewPager).

I want to disable the button when the image is loading and re-enable it when the image is visible.

How can I know the status of the current page (if the image is beeing displayed or not) from the Activity containing the ViewPager?

Thanks

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: do you have fragments in view pager or just views??

Comment: just views, I have not code yet, will post it asap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `setPrimaryItem` function

```
public void setPrimaryItem(android.view.ViewGroup container,
int position, Object object) {
super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
    //check if image is loaded here
};
```